# Android weather widget with daily snowfall projection and/or configurable alerts?

Tags: android, widget, weather

Are there any Android weather apps with one of the following two features?

- Widget that shows daily snow accumulation forecast, preferably alongside precipitation probability
- Alerts or widget states that I can configure based on certain thresholds being met, e.g. it tells me if and only if today there is either a >20% chance of rain between 8am and 8pm OR a low of <0 Celsius

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer on snowfall accumulation: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloud3squared.meteogram (I am not affiliated). This shows anticipated precipitation accumulation by 2-to-4-hour block, along with a binary indicator of "precipitation predicted yes/no" for each block. I'm loving it so far.